# ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, rerender, react-18

Im using rerender and renderHook in react testing library. Recently upgraded react version to 18. Got below error in one of the test case.

console.error
Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot

rerender();
renderHook(() => abc());

Since, im not using render why the warning is pointing rerender and renderHook as render.

Could you please point how to dig this issue further.

Comment: Can you post what versions of packages you are using?

Answer (score 11):

instead of using "@testing-library/react-hooks" use "@testing-library/react"

```
import { renderHook, act } from "@testing-library/react";
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps all you need to do is to update the version of `@testing-library`. Try the followings,

```
npm i --save-dev @testing-library/react@latest
npm i --save-dev @testing-library/jest-dom@latest
npm i --save-dev @testing-library/user-event@latest
```

To be clear, it's good to empty your node_modules and reinstall all.

```
rm -rf ./node_modules
npm i
```

This is how my case had been resolved.